# ¿Como iterar 2 Objetos distintos en el mismo each en Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

He estado intentando querer iterar 2 objetos distintos en Rails, tengo 2 recursos uno de "Noticias" y otros de "articulos", entonces quiero que los 2 iteren de forma paralela en la misma seccion y se vayan agregando segun el orden de fecha publicacion dentro de mi index, investigando, logre encontrar el poder crear una interacion array de esta forma:

```
lista = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
lista.each do |number|
  puts "Iteración número #{number}" 
end
```

Sin embargo no estoy muy seguro como podria quedar usando los 2 recursos antes mencionados:

```
<% list = [@enterprise.articles, @enterprise.news] %>
<% list.each do |article, new| %>
<%= article.name %>
<%= new.name %>
<% end %>
```

Sin embargo no es del todo correcto esta forma, por lo visto, espero puedan ayudarme con la inquietud, estaré atento a sus respuestas, saludos! =D

PD: He logrado hacerlo con esto:

```
<% @enterprise.articles.zip(@enterprise.news).each do |(article, new)| %>

    <h5><%= article.name %></h5>
    <h5><%= new.name %></h5>

<% end %>
```

Pero si no tengo una noticia, no me muestra el otro registro de articulo, tiene q mostrarse de par en par y quiero que se muestre independientemente sea par o no

Answer (score 0):

Pues utilizar el método [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) para poder combinar cada elemento de varios arrays. Aquí tienes una pequeña demostración:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
a.zip(b)  #=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Para tu caso particular, bastaría con hacer lo siguiente:

```
<% list = [@enterprise.articles, @enterprise.news] %>
<% list[0].zip(list[1]) do |article, new| %>
  <%= article.name %>
  <%= new.name %>
<% end %>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Madh, pero en este caso este ¿no es capaz de ir replicando?

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo haciendolo de esta forma, y va perfecto:

enterprises_controller.rb

```
def show
  @items = @enterprise.jobs + @enterprise.products
  @items = @items.sort_by do |item| item.created_at end
  @items = @items.reverse
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @items = @items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.name %> | <%= item.created_at %> <br>
<% end %>
```